# Showing that Gale-Stewart Theorem on Determinacy of Open and Closed Games is equivalent to AC

Tags: proof-verification, axiom-of-choice, descriptive-set-theory, infinite-games

I'm studying from Kechris' "Classical Descriptive Set Theory" and I'm trying to solve exercise 20.3, which asks to show that the Gale-Stewart theorem is equivalent  to the axiom of choice AC in ZF. I'm of course interested only in the implication Gale Thm $\Rightarrow AC$. I recall the theorem:

> Let $T$ be a non-empty pruned tree on a set $U$. Let $W\subseteq[T]$ be open or closed in $[T]$. Then $G(T,W)$ is determined.

I recall also a formal statement of AC :

> $\forall X[\emptyset \not\in X \Longrightarrow \exists f:X \rightarrow \bigcup X \quad \forall A \in X (f(A) \in A)]$

I think I solved it, but I'm now sure and I doubt it was the smartest way to do it. So, following the previous notation, what I did is taking the set $U = X \cup \bigcup X$ and defining a tree $T \subseteq U^{<\mathbb{N}}$ with the condition:

- $(a_0) \in T \iff a_0 \neq \emptyset$
- $(a_0,a_1) \in T \iff a_1 \in a_0$
- $(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n) \in T \iff a_n = a_1$

and then taking $W = \emptyset$. The hypotheses of Gale-Stewart thm are satisfied, so we have a winning strategy $\sigma: T \rightarrow U$ for player II. In fact, player I cannot have a winning strategy. Let's suppose otherwise, let's call $\sigma_1$ a winning strategy for I, then we'd have that, given a constant strategy for II $\sigma_2: T \mapsto c \in \sigma_1(\emptyset)$, the play $\sigma_1 \otimes \sigma_2 \in \emptyset$, which is absurd.

Then a choice function would be: $$A \in X, f(A) = \sigma((A))$$
What do you think?

EDIT: isn't Dependent Choice necessary to extract a play given two strategies like I did when proving that I cannot have a winning strategy?
EDIT 2: now it should not need DC

Comment: "open or closed" is *more* than clopen.

Comment: yes, I corrected the title. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to argue that the winning strategy cannot be for Player I. This much is easy, of course, but needs to be mentioned.

Other than this, the proof is fine.

**Response to the Edit.** The proof is better, yes. And $\sf DC$ is not needed here, since your tree has height $3$.

---

This proof is almost the same as the proof that $p\Vdash\exists x\varphi(x)$ implies $\exists\dot x\, p\Vdash\varphi(\dot x)$, in the context of forcing.

Comment: I edited the proof, could you check it?

Comment: I've edited the answer, you can read it. :)

Comment: Thanks! But how can the height of the tree T be 3 if it is pruned?

Comment: Oh ok. Maybe I could ask the tree to be of "height" 3 by imposing that after the third layer it doesn't branch anymore. In this way DC is not needed even if the height is $\omega$

Comment: You already did that. Look at the way you defined $T$ (there was no root, which I artificially added to your tree).

Comment: I edited the definition of T. As it was defined before it was too large, basically after the third layer it included the entire $U^{<\mathbb{N}}$ tree. Hence It would have needed DC to extract the play, right?

Comment: Not really. If Player I somehow plays moves that force playing into a tree without branches, then at some stage $n$, there are no more legal moves inside that tree. This is one of those paradoxical situations that fail because a game defines a branch. So there's no single point it would fail, it just would have to eventually go outside of that tree. Since $U^{<\Bbb N}$ has *all* the sequences, and we are talking about Gale-Stewart games only, that *should* be fine. (I have not checked this, though.)

Comment: Also, note that your original definition only allowed sequences of length $1$ and $2$ (and $0$ for a root) to be in the tree. Maybe it's better to have required $a_0\in X$ rather than $a_0\neq\varnothing$. Nevertheless. You only get very short sequences. How would that imply that we have "the whole tree above it"? The revised definition is equally good, but it's a bit redundant.

Comment: Yes, you are right, the previous definition was wrong. I don't see why it is a bit redundant the new one. I stress that I need to defined a pruned tree to apply the theorem. The previously defined tree (including only short sequences) was not pruned.

Comment: Ah, you're right.